# show invalid messages on entering wrong input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have written a code stuff using bootstrap-datetimepicker which has two datetime picker start and end. Code is working fine but I don't know how to show validation to the date time textfield. say for example in the datetime picker textfield when I enter some invalid date, it should validate and show invalid date. How can we achieve that.

Can anyone please help me on this

My code is as given below

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jn442w6/)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:75px;">
       <div class='col-md-5'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>Start</div>

                <div class='input-group date' id='startDate'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="startDate" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-5'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>End</div>

                <div class='input-group date' id='endDate'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="org_endDate" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/5jn442w6/1/ let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 2):

Check out the docs regarding options: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/

I've never used this plugin but it looks like passing some of these in would allow you to set validation parameters and not have to write too much more code.

Things like:

- `format` (using moment.js notations)
- `minDate` & `maxDate`
- `disabledDates`
- and looks like `useStrict` might also be helpful depending on what your requirements are.

Answer (score 2):

Yo. `validate.js` is very easy to implement. It's also very easy to customize.

Simple demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/winstonion/5RrGa/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").validate();
  });
```

Read more about [Validate.js](http://validatejs.org/)